# Use KONG as API Gateway to GraphQL/REST services

Tags: microservices, graphql, kong

I'm trying to understand if it's possible to use KONG as API Gateway to microservices implementing REST and/or GraphQL interfaces

As API Gateway will expose a GraphQL API and will request to our microservices currently implemented in REST/GraphQL and grpc coming soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can route the Graphql as any other HTTP request but it doesn't parse graphql to route each bit to a a specific service

Answer (score 1):

Kong can front any RESTful API and through a transformation plugin you should be able to deal with GraphQL API as well.

Comment: Checking Kon [transformation plugin](https://getkong.org/plugins/request-transformer) it's difficult to understand how implement a composition of services before hiting upstream servers

Comment: Not sure about it but they have mentioned here: https://github.com/Kong/kong/issues/1889